# How do I create an LSTM using Keras for variable sized blocks?

Tags: python, keras, lstm, keras-layer

I am trying to create an LSTM using Keras but I'm struggling to lay it out. Essentially I have several time blocks, each with a variable number of arrays that are each of size 3. The following is a diagram of this: 
| - Time block - | - -  Array 1 - - | - - Array 2  - - | - - Array 3 - - | ... 
| - - - - 1 - - - - - | < 3-vector > | < 3-vector > | 
| - - - - 2 - - - - - | < 3-vector > | 
| - - - - 3 - - - - - | < 3-vector > | < 3-vector > | < 3-vector > | 
... 
Each time block is just an element in the sequence and the arrays in each time block are in arbitrary order (they don't correspond with one another and there should be no difference if they were in a different order). 
The output for this input should be an array with a 1 or 0 for each 3-vector e.g. [[[3, 4, 2], [2, 3, 4]], [[1, 3, 4]]] -> [[1, 0], [1]]

 The below is what I've come up with but it is very faulty.

```
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
model = Sequential()
# fixed feature size of 3, unknown number of vectors
model.add(LSTM(64, input_dim=3, input_length=None, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(LSTM(64, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
# number of outputs is the (previously unknown) number of vectors
model.add(Dense(None, activation='sigmoid')) # obviously this is incorrect...

# Example training phase:
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='mean_squared_error', \
    metrics=['accuracy'])
x_train = [np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4,5,6]]), \
           np.array([[4, 1, 4], [1, 1, 5], [3, 2, 1]]), \
           np.array([[3, 2, 1], [2, 3, 2]]), \
           np.array([[7, 4, 3], [2, 6, 4], [2, 5, 7], [3, 8, 5]])]
y_train = [np.array([0, 0]), np.array([0, 1, 0]), \
    np.array([1, 1, 0]), np.array([0, 0, 0, 1])]
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=2000, batch_size=3)
# Testing/evaluating phase would be similar to the above
```

The above was my primary question. In addition, in my training data, there will be far more 1s than 0s since the data is very imbalanced - almost a 2500:1 ratio (and this is the real-life ratio so collecting more data doesn't change this). If this were a feedforward network I could eliminate some of the data corresponding to 0s to balance it out (via undersampling). Clearly I can't do that with an LSTM - so how should I train the model accounting for the imbalanced classes?

Comment: I don't understand, if the arrays under the same time block are unrelated, why using an LSTM at all? I don't see the point in that.

Comment: @Anis let me explain my problem. I have a graph of nodes that varies over time and for each node I extract 3 features. Every x number of seconds, I extract the features for all the nodes present. Note that while many of the previous nodes are still in the graph, some will be new and some will be old. I am searching for outlier nodes and my thinking was that they will be more easily found if we detect some change over time (hence the LSTM).